# ​[driving] a [vehicle] in [traffic]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have [driving](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/driving), [vehicle](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle), and [traffic](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traffic). I can see the point of [vehicle](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) being separate ("On what day of the month do vehicle registrations expire?" or "Can my insurance company refuse to cover damage from my own golf ball accidentally hitting my parked car's window?" are related to [vehicle](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle)s but not [traffic](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traffic) or [driving](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/driving)), but I don't see any difference between [traffic](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traffic) and [driving](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/driving). Should we merge them?

Comment: Related, to varying degrees: [Tags for "traffic" questions](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/247/35069), [What is the difference between ^vehicle^ and ^motor-vehicle^?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1054/35069), and [Should "traffic" and "traffic-laws" be synonymized?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/214/35069)

Comment: There's considerable overlap between the two tags, which would suggest a case for them being merged as synonyms. Driving could apply in cases where there is no traffic (eg private land), so maybe traffic should become a synonym of driving?